# Instantiating a subclass of a generic parent statically from another class in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have a generic class that looks like:

```
public abstract class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {...
```

and another class that looks like:

```
public abstract class Fum<T extends Fum<T,U>, U extends Foo<U>> {...
```

and finally some subclasses that look like:

```
public class SubFoo extends Foo<SubFoo> {...

public class SubFum extends Fum<SubFum,SubFoo> {...
```

In the abstract classes, there are abstract methods declared `public abstract T create();` (with overloaded versions) which are responsible for instantiating subclass objects used in the superclass' methods.

However, I obviously cannot simply write `new U()` in `Fum` to get an instance of `SubFoo`, so I want some static placeholder method that I can override. However, I obviously can't write `public static abstract T create();` because of whatever reasons I can't fathom.

Therefore, I wrote a method in `Fum` that looks like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected static <V extends Foo<V>> V newSubFoo() {
    try {//create() requires a constructed object to work.
        return (V) Foo.class.asSubclass(Foo.class).newInstance().create();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
        return null;
    }//I don't expect this to work, but I don't know what to use before 
}   // the "asSubclass" call.
```

which manages to make the compiler shut up. However, this does not appear to be getting me anywhere.

In conclusion: Is there some way to construct a new object of the type `U` in `Fum` using a static method that can be overridden in `SubFoo` (preferably without writing a blank constructor in `Foo`)?

Comment: Static Method cannot be overridden by his subclass.

Comment: If you just want to make subclass by superclass's static method.you can write as `public static <U extends Foo<U>> U newSubFoo(Class<U> cls) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException  {
  return  cls.newInstance().create();
 }`,give it the class type of what he want to create.

Comment: to call `public abstract T create();` you need an instance of the sublcass, so what's the need of that?